# PYQT-4 Error : QPainter::begin: Paint device returned engine == 0, Type =3

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt4

I have a weird problem. I have some pyqt-4 code setup to paint and capture images for urls specified. Here is that code :

```
def save_page(webpage, output):
    global error
    global AWSError
    # Set the size of the (virtual) browser window
    webpage.setViewportSize(webpage.mainFrame().contentsSize())
    # Paint this frame into an image
    image = QImage(webpage.viewportSize(), QImage.Format_ARGB32)
    painter = QPainter(image)
    webpage.mainFrame().render(painter)
    painter.setOpacity(opacity)
    painter.setPen(QtCore.Qt.blue)
    painter.setFont(QtGui.QFont('arial', 15))
    painter.drawText(image.rect(), QtCore.Qt.AlignVertical_Mask | QtCore.Qt.AlignRight , WaterMarktxt + ' ' + str(now.strftime(" %d. %B %Y %I:%M%p")))
    painter.end()

    image.save(ImageDestinationPath + "/" + output + ".png")
```

Now I specify multiple urls to the applciation and they get processed absolutely fine but when I process http://www.google.com (it redirects to https) I get an error. Here is the stack. Please note image id = 0000..1 is for google , image id = 0000.. is for all other urls.

```
Processing SourceImageId: 000000001
QPainter::begin: Paint device returned engine == 0, type: 3
QPainter::setRenderHint: Painter must be active to set rendering hints
QPainter::setBrush: Painter not active
QPainter::pen: Painter not active
QPainter::setPen: Painter not active
QPainter::setOpacity: Painter not active
QPainter::setPen: Painter not active
QPainter::setFont: Painter not active
QPainter::end: Painter not active, aborted
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: './SourceImagePath/000000001.png'
True :results
url still left to be painted.
QFont::setPixelSize: Pixel size <= 0 (0)
called onLoadFinished
***********************************************************

Response from the webpage : True
Processing SourceImageId: 000000000
000000000.png image successfully saved to S3
sourceimage id: 000000000 name of the file: 000000000.png error: None
000000000.png image removed from local folder
True :results
QWaitCondition: Destroyed while threads are still waiting
```

As you can see it fails to form the image for google whereas successfully does so for almost all other urls. Any specific reason ? Is it to do with capacity of image or size of image I specify ?

Comment: What does `image.isNull()` return? If `True`, that would be the reason why the painter is not set active upon construction.

Comment: @sebastian - exactly my point, why is it only for this url (google) that it fails to produce an image and not for the others.

Comment: I meant for google it returns True for other urls it returns false. Every single time.

Comment: Maybe because google is the first in your loop (guessing based on your id-numbering)? What does `mainFrame().contentsSize()` return?